# Quote for creating design for website without developing the site?

Tags: price, design

I have a client that has hired another website developer agency to create his website, but he wants me to design a better layout for the agency to implement since he isn't happy with what they have for him. I'm not completely sure what I should charge for this job, since it's kind if a odd job. Any ideas about what I should charge for this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Freelancing SE! Why not just take your rate multiplied by the amount of time it takes you to design a layout? I'm assuming you normally do design, but it's not clear in your question. If it's really more complicated than that, I encourage you to [edit] your post to clarify so you get the best possible answers. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what we do in our team.

1. If we are to make a completely new design, then I set up a fixed price for that.
2. If the client wants to keep existing design and our designer should "make existing design better", then you should definitely go with hourly price since "a simple shine effect" may cost you 10 work hours.

But this is only a general suggestion. Talk to your client what he really needs then come back here for advise.

Answer (score 0):

Its best to ask this question directly to your client. I generally give a questionnaire to my client before starting the work which at the end will have my billing/breakups. I also provide an option whether the client want to pay in installments or in an advance-afterComplete way. Either way its a win for us.

Calculate how much time it will take and decide how much to ask. Divide the total amount by hours and tell your client your hourly rate. I am sure he/she will give a nod.

If its a simple design layout, it should not take more than 4 hours ( I am not including the brainstorming you will do with your client or peers)

Good Luck !

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like they want you to create a website template. There are two options:

1) If you charge by the hour, then quote a fair estimated number of hours you would require to complete the template.

2) If you charge by the job, anticipate this being a common thing, and charge accordingly. You can either inflate slightly than #1 would be b/c you aren't doing the full site, or you could offer a discount on the hourly rate for whatever reason sounds marketable.